# How can I initialize the hidden state (carry) of a (flax linen) GRUCell as a learnable parameter (e.g. using model.init)

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, jax, gru, flax

I create a GRU model in Jax using Flax and I initialize the model parameters using model.init as follows:

```py
import jax.numpy as np
from jax import random
import flax.linen as nn
from jax.nn import initializers

class RNN(nn.Module):
    n_RNN_units: int

    @nn.compact
    def __call__(self, carry, inputs):
        
        carry, outputs = nn.GRUCell()(carry, inputs)
        
        return carry, outputs
    
    def init_state(self):
        
        return nn.GRUCell.initialize_carry((), (), self.n_RNN_units, init_fn = initializers.zeros)

# instantiate an RNN (GRU) model
n_RNN_units = 200
model = RNN(n_RNN_units = n_RNN_units)

# initialize the parameters of the model (weights and biases)
data_dim = 20
params = model.init(carry = np.empty((n_RNN_units,)), inputs = np.empty((data_dim,)), rngs = {'params': random.PRNGKey(1)})
```

Unfortuantely for me, the FrozenDict params created by model.init only contains the weight and biases of the GRU, not the initial hidden state (carry). Is there a way that I can tell model.init 1) that I also want to learn the initial hidden state and 2) specify the initializer function for the initial hidden state.

Alternatively, if there is a better way to do this that does not involve using model.init, feel free to suggest that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.param` to register a tensor as parameters:

```py
@nn.compact
def __call__(self, inputs, carry=None):
    if carry is None:
        # Learnable initial carry
        carry = self.param('carry_init', lambda rng, shape: jnp.zeros(shape), (self.n_RNN_units,))
    carry, outputs = nn.GRUCell()(carry, inputs)
    return carry, outputs
```

Now `carry_init` is in model parameters after `model.init(rng, inputs, None)`.

What happen now is that `model.apply` takes parameters `params` with `carry_init` on it so gradients w.r.t to it will be computed as usual with `grad`.

More precisely when you are making a prediction of a sequence, you have to start your calls with `carry, outputs = model.apply(params, inputs)`. It will use `carry_init` in `params` then for the following calls use `carry, outputs = model.apply(params, inputs, carry)`. It will use `carry` now and the `carry_init` is indirectly on the computation graph of outputs and carry as the initial carry so you can propagate gradient on it. However you should care about potentially heavy gradient vanishing for it if you have long sequences so you may consider using all the values (especially the first) of your sequences to compute the loss or adapting a dedicated learning rate based on sequence length.

Details of `linen.Module.param` in the Flax documntation [Managing Parameters and State](https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/state_params.html).

Comment: self.param(...) looks useful, although I'm not sure your example solution is quite what I need, as I still want carry to be an argument of the __ call __ method. The RNN model I am creating recursively updates the carry over time, and I only want the initial carry (i.e. the carry passed as an argument to the RNN with the very first input) to be a learnable parameter. Can your example be tweaked for this situation?